# How to add new charecters to a Lottie Animation

Tags: android, lottie

I downloaded an animation from LottieFiles, and I want to change the text of the animation.

#### What I have tried

I tried using the Lottie online editor, but it didn't work, the text was not updating correctly, so I tried to manually edit the JSON file

#### What I found

I noticed that the JSON file has an array named `chars` this array does not contain all characters, bingo!

Looks like the Lottie online editor does not add the chars to this array, so I need to add the characters of my string for the animation to work. (this is my hypothesis)

The char has the following structure

```
"chars": [
  {
    "ch": "W",
    "size": 150,
    "style": "SemiBold",
    "w": 99.9,
    "data": {
      "shapes": [...]
    },
    "family": "Gilroy"
  }
]
```

#### Question

How can I add new characters?

I don't have experience with Adobe After Effects, is there any way to find the `data` for each char or an easy way to extract this info from After Effects?